# Как открыть порт в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, порты, linux

Я новичок в ubuntu, поэтому никак не могу понять, почему порт не открывается и как это всё-таки сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Я пробовал открыть порт в iptables, но, как я понял, iptables служат для управления файерволлом ufw, а при вводе команды `sudo ufw status` получаю ответ:

```
sudo: ufw: command not found
```

Как в таком случае открыть порт? Гугление мне посоветовало лишь iptables.

На всякий случай приведу выход команды `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTENtcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTENtcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTENtcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTENtcp        0      0 5.231.61.235:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTENtcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTENtcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTENtcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTENtcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTENtcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTENtcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTENtcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTENtcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTENunix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3215411995 /var/run/cups/cups.sockunix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3215409707 /var/run/avahi-daemon/socketunix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3215403381 @/com/ubuntu/upstartunix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3215406175 /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socketunix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3215553140 /var/run/sendmail/mta/smcontrolunix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3215421071 /var/run/acpid.socketunix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     3215405745 /run/udev/controlunix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3215427067 /var/run/saslauthd/mux
```

То есть вроде как 53-й порт открыт... Как бы ещё портов открыть?

Comment: Покажите вывод команды: iptables -L -n -v

Comment: Вывод команды: iptables-save В студию

Comment: это так, между прочим... это скорее ufw морда к iptables :) хотя на само деле iptables это такая морда для управления файрволом ядру.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ваш листинг это не открытые порты, а вывод того кто какие порты слушает.

Если вы хотите например открыть порт 53 по tcp,  используя утилиту iptables :

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Точно! Что-то меня переклинило, давно с портами дело не имел, поэтому почему-то решил, что если порт открыт, то он сразу же и должен показываться как открытый, даже если его никто не слушает!Стоило запустить программу, слущающую нужный порт - и стало всё в порядке!Спасибо за вправление мозга, прошу прощения за глупый вопрос =)

Answer (score 0):

если речь идет именно про ubuntu, и после ее установки никаких ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫХ действий над файерволом не предпринималось, то У НЕЕ ОТКРЫТЫ ВСЕ порты

Answer (score -1):

Установите ufw утилиту:

```
apt-get install ufw
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста , как установка этой утилиты отвечает на вопрос топиккастера?