# Не могу открыть порт сервера Ubuntu xenial

Tags: сервер, iptables

Cуть проблемы: нужно открыть порт, но вводом различных команд iptables, успехом это дело не увенчается.

Например ввожу

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT`

в iptables -L 53 порт сохраняется, однако из внешней сети он остается закрытым. А после перезагрузки сервера, все нововведения в iptables сбрасываются к изначальным. Не помогли и iptables-persistense, iptables-save, iptables-apply. В чем может быть причина?

Из моих замечаний по данной проблеме:

- На сервере стоит fail2ban
- В некоторых руководствах упомянуто `service iptables start`, но у меня отсутствует данный service.
- При вводе команды `sudo iptables-apply`, выводит ошибку `Error: rulesfile not readable: /etc/network/iptables.up.rules`

Comment: А почему tcp? Может все таки udp протокол. Либо если действительно нужен и tcp, то добавьте еще правило для udp.

Comment: какая политика используется для цепочки `INPUT`? Что есть внешняя сеть? Покажите пример, как вы используете команды для сохранения правил

Comment: в общем, начинать надо сначала. как именно вы определили, что у вас этот порт закрыт? (вообще, судя по приведённой информации, с огромной долей вероятности, присуствует «[ошибка xy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)»)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, следуя рекомендациям из похожего вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/347145/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B2-ubuntu
открытые порты определяю с помощью nmap со стороннего устройства. Сервер практически стоковый, особо ничего не перенастраивалось. Редактирую iptables, но порты не открываются. Такое ощущение, что iptables только ограничивать может, а сами порты открываются с помощью чего-то что стоит выше файрвола. К сожалению у меня не достаточно знаний, чтобы решить этот вопрос самостоятельно

Comment: *а сами порты открываются с помощью чего-то что стоит выше файрвола* — примерно так и есть (если слова «стоит выше» заменить на «не имеет отношения к»): порты «открываются» прикладными программами.