# Интеграция nodejs в Drupal 7 c CloudFlare

Tags: drupal, drupal7

Интеграция nodejs в Drupal 7.Как настроить модуль что надо иметь на сервере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Установка `nodejs` и `npm` на операционную систему. Можно просто найти как
2. Установить пакет `drupal-node.js`

   cd /var/aegir/platforms/photon_tec-7.0.2/sites/dev.bcltec.com
   npm install drupal-node.js
3. Настройка конфигурации сервера nodejs.

   cd /var/aegir/platforms/photon_tec-7.0.2/sites/dev.bcltec.com/node_modules/drupal-node.js

Создать файл конфигураций с примера

```
cp nodejs.config.js.example nodejs.config.js
```

Открыть его

```
sudo nano nodejs.config.js
```

Следующим контентом

```
settings = {
  scheme: 'https',
  port: 8888,
  host: '206.189.150.100',
  resource: '/socket.io',
  serviceKey: '1111',
  backend: {
    port: 443,
    host: 'dev.bcltec.com',
    scheme: 'https',
    basePath: '',
    messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
  },
  debug: false,
  sslKeyPath: '/var/aegir/config/ssl.d/bcltec.com/openssl.key',
  sslCertPath: '/var/aegir/config/ssl.d/bcltec.com/openssl.crt',
  sslCAPath: '',
  baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
  // расширение для примера, потом можно будет убрать его
  extensions: ["example_extension.js"],
  clientsCanWriteToChannels: true,
  clientsCanWriteToClients: true,
  transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
  jsMinification: true,
  jsEtag: true,
  logLevel: 1
};
```

4. Открыть порт 8888 
     iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888--jump ACCEPT
     iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 --jump ACCEPT
     iptables-save
5. Запуск сервера nodejs

   node app.js

И сервер запустился с сообщением в консоли

```
Started https server.
```

Проверка работы сервера

https://206.189.150.100:8888/example

Должно вывестись в браузере  - Hello World

**Запуск сервера nodejs в фоновом режиме**

1. cd /var/aegir/platforms/photon_tec-7.0.2/sites/dev.bcltec.com

   npm install forever -g

   cd node_modules/drupal-node.js

   forever start app.js

https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

На этом настройка drupal-node.js закончена

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Настройка поддомена для NodeJs и конфигурация прокси

поддомен njs.dev.bcltec.com нужно настроить согласно этой инструкции
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168756-How-do-I-add-a-subdomain-to-my-site-

Установка прокси согласно этой инструкции https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Конфигурация хоста njs.dev.bcltec.com.conf

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
touch njs.dev.bcltec.com.conf
nano njs.dev.bcltec.com.conf

ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia full

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

ProxyPass / https://206.189.150.100:8888/
ProxyPassReverse / https://206.189.150.100:8888/

ServerName njs.dev.bcltec.com

SSLCertificateFile /var/aegir/config/ssl.d/bcltec.com/openssl.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/aegir/config/ssl.d/bcltec.com/openssl.key
```

a2ensite njs.dev.bcltec.com.conf
service apache2 reload

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Настройка модуля nodejs в Drupal**

Включить следущие модули

Nodejs Config
Nodejs integration
Nodejs Notifications - для провверки работы

идем в /admin/config/nodejs/config

Протокол - https
Host - njs.dev.bcltec.com
Node.js service key - 1111

Answer (score 0):

Для начала очень просто можно глянуть принцып работы модуля nodejs на примере тех же логов
Например на сайте есть админ который смотрит логи пока пользователи совершают действия. 
Когда админ зашел на страницу логов запущеный сервер nodejs провел его аутентификацию и знает что он присутсвует на сайте. Когда какой то пользователь совершает дейвие которое нужно записать в логи, после записи в логи запускається ajaxCallback который шлет message

```
nodejs_send_content_channel_message($message)
```

на запущеный сервер nodejs. Который уже выводит админу новые логи без перезагрузки страницы инструментами NodeJS

Drupal начинает общение с NodeJS в момент

```
Drupal.Nodejs.connect();
```

в файле

```
sites/all/modules/nodejs/nodejs.js
```

**Настройка drupal-node.js**

1. Установка `nodejs` и `npm` на операционную систему. Можно просто найти как
2. Перейти в корень сайта на один уровень к index.php и установить пакет `drupal-node.js`

   npm install drupal-node.js
3. Настройка конфигурации сервера nodejs. Перейти в директорию

   cd node_modules/drupal-node.js

Создать файл конфигураций с примера

```
cp nodejs.config.js.example nodejs.config.js
```

Открыть его

```
sudo nano nodejs.config.js
```

Дальше я представлю пример своих конфигураций

```
settings = {
  // сервер nodejs будет работать с подтвержденным сертификатом SSL
  scheme: 'https',
  // указываем порт на котором запустим его, потом будет нужно открыть этот порт
  port: 8888,
  // ваш хост, наиболее просто использовать тот же хост сайта 
  host: 'veriga.space',
  // с помощью чего будет работь сервер nodejs, не нужно изменять, так как это нарушит интеграцию с Drupal
  resource: '/socket.io',
  // Секретный ключ для того что бы никто кроме вас не мог слать запросы к этому серверу nodejs.Вам нужно его придумать и потом нужно будет еще его указать в настройке модуля nodejs в самом Drupal
  serviceKey: '1111',
  // сайт с которым будет общаться 
  backend: {
    // если сверху мы указали что схема будет https, тогда сдесь мы так же обязаны использовать ее. Иначе будет как мининум Mixed Content и вам нужно будет делать много лишних настроек 
    port: 443,
    host: 'veriga.space',
    scheme: 'https',
    // эти две настройки по умолчанию нужно оставить
    basePath: '',
    messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
  },
  //  при запуске (node app.js) будут выводиться в консоль логи или нет 
  debug: false,
  // пути к ключам, они должны у вас быть, если нужно сгенирировать  можно использовать [https://certbot.eff.org/][1] 
  sslKeyPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/veriga.space/privkey.pem',
  sslCertPath: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/veriga.space/fullchain.pem',
  sslCAPath: '',
  // оставить по умолчанию
  baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
  // расширение для примера, потом можно будет убрать его
  extensions: ["example_extension.js"],
  // включаем 
  clientsCanWriteToChannels: true,
  clientsCanWriteToClients: true,
  // просто оставляем по умолчанию, что это можно будет понять во врямя работы
  transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
  jsMinification: true,
  jsEtag: true,
  logLevel: 1
};
```

3. Запуск сервера nodejs

   node app.js

В этот момент у вас будут ошыбки

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 104.27.182.127:8888
```

Эта ошибка значит(ERROR ADDRESS NOT AVAILABLE) что данный порт закрыт у вас в операционной системе и нужно его открыть
[Открыть порт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/347145/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B2-ubuntu)

```
fs.js:119
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
```

Эта ошибка значит что не был найдет файл ssl сертификатов и вам нужно проверить sslKeyPath, sslCertPath

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:80
```

Использовать другой порт

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8080
```

(ERROR ADDRESS IN USE)
Порт уже используеться чем нибуть другим,  простой вариант выбрать другой порт

Других ошыбок у меня не было.
И сервер запустился с сообщением в консоли

```
Started https server.
```

На этом настройка drupal-node.js закончена

**Настройка модуля nodejs в Drupal**

для начала идем в /admin/config/nodejs/config

Протокол - https
Host - veriga.space
Node.js service key - 1111

Еще в этот момент у меня была одна ошибка

```
Error reaching the Node.js server at "nodejs/health/check": [0] Error opening socket ssl://veriga.space:8888.
```

Эта ошибка возникает в файле /includes/common.inc в методе `drupal_http_request`

когда Drupal пытаеться отправить запрос nodejs серверу(проверить его версию) используя при этом функцию

```
stream_socket_client
```

в которой с версии php5.6 просто невозможно использовать неподтвержденный сертификат SSL поэтому она и возвращает FALSE.

Возможна еще ошибка

```
Error reaching the Node.js server at "nodejs/health/check": [-111] Connection refused.
```

Это значит что вы забыли запустить nodejs сурвер

**Запуск сервера nodejs в фоновом режиме**

1. в корне сайта

   npm install forever -g

   cd node_modules/drupal-node.js

   forever start app.js

[forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)